# Loop a sound while a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener, soundpool

I'm trying to loop a sound while a button is pressed down.

How could I do that while I'm pressing the button hadling the event "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN" will not stop running the sound? The way I have done it only runs once. I've tryied to change the return statement to false, but it doesn't works.

The setLoop MediaPlayer option does not help me because I want to continue playing new sounds although the current sound doesn't finished playing.

Here's my code:

```
public boolean onClick(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        //here should not stop running the soundPool
        soundPool.play(R.raw.sound1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        // stop running the soundpool
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the fifth argument to -1 :

```
soundPool.play(R.raw.sound1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1);
```

As of the [play() doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play%28int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float%29) the *fifth* argument `loop` takes either 0 ( = no loop), or -1 ( = loop forever)

Comment: it makes the same sound loop, I want to run the sound many times as a new independent soundpool without allowing it to stop the execution of the others.

To give you an idea, I want to play a sound of a machinegun playing the sound of a bullet many times.

Comment: Yes, it's just a single raw of a bullet sound but I don't want to loop it, I want to repeat the execution of this soundPool while the event is the ACTION_DOWN. I want to do like that because I want to start a new sound before the end of the previous one and not lose the echo of the sound of the bullet shot.

The problem is that the ACTION_DOWN only responds one time and I want always an active listener.

Thanks!

Forgive me if I'm not explain it correctly.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure but you can try implementing a `OnTouchListener` instead of a OnClickListener and override the `onTouch` method the same way you did with the onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return false;` with `return true;`. The only way to get `ACTION_UP` is by returning `true` to inform Android system that you will handle the whole `onClick` event.